# offline - Launch Unity with MongoDB Realm

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I’m building a game in unity and the players' data are stored in a MongoDB Realm DB with Sync enabled.
When I launch the game online, it works fine and if I close and re-open, the user is still here.

My problem occurs when I close, set offline mode on my device, and get back: it’s not finding any users.
When looking on "set up realm for unity" tutorials, they always talk about the "new PartitionSyncConfiguration" instead of getting the stored one. Being offline is it just not a Realm Sync feature?
Hope you’ve got some answers ;)

```
realmApp = App.Create(new AppConfiguration(AppId)
{
    MetadataPersistenceMode = MetadataPersistenceMode.NotEncrypted
});

if (realmApp.CurrentUser == null)
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("user_login");
}
else
{
    // Does not work offline
    realmUser = realmApp.CurrentUser;
    realmInstance = await Realm.GetInstanceAsync(new PartitionSyncConfiguration(realmUser.Id, realmUser));
    SceneManager.LoadScene("project_list");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to a MongoDB Employee, who founded me the solution (and guess what, it’s stupid) :
https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/offline-launch-unity-with-mongodb-realm/148914

```
var config = new PartitionSyncConfiguration(realmUser.Id, realmUser);
    try
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(10_000); // cancel after 10s
        realmInstance = await Realm.GetInstanceAsync(config, cts.Token);
    }
    catch (TaskCancelledException)
    {
        // GetInstanceAsync timed out, let's fall back to using the local data
        realmInstance = Realm.GetInstance(config);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

request the saved data from the MongoDB in Void Awake () {}.
and you can search on youtube [Unity MongoDB](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-3NNV93jDE)

Comment: Thanks, it helps me clarify the problem. Its already in "Void OnEnable"

Comment: Can you make the correct is green, this means that this question has been answered (I mean the picture correctly) under the title answer

Comment: Yeah but this actually dont answser my question